# Popup Login Issue with react-native-app-auth in React Native

Tags: react-native, authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth

I'm encountering an issue with implementing a popup login using react-native-app-auth in my React Native project. I'm using the library for Google authentication and would like to have the login process happen within a popup instead of redirecting to an external browser.

**Details**

- react-native-app-auth: 7.0.0
- Platform: Android, IOS

```
import {authorize} from 'react-native-app-auth';

const config = {
  issuer: 'https://accounts.google.com',
  clientId:
    Platform.OS === 'ios'
      ? '60164497777-d3a68pcxxxxxxxxx72.apps.googleusercontent.com'
      : '60164497777-d3a68pcxxxxxxxxx72.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  redirectUrl:
    Platform.OS === 'ios'
      ? 'org.app:/oauthredirect'
      : 'com.app:/oauthredirect',
  scopes: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage',
    'openid',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
  ],
  useProxy: true,
};

 async function signInWithGoogle() {
    try {
      const authState = await authorize(config);
      // Handle authentication success
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle authentication errors
    }
  }
......
 <TouchableOpacity style={styles.card} onPress={() => signInWithGoogle()}>
        <ProfileIcon style={{marginRight: 11}} />
        <AppText>Google Login</AppText>
 </TouchableOpacity>
...
```

Current behaviour

[image: When click on login button it redirect to browser]

Expected Behaviour
When one clicks on the login button popup appears or one taps sign in
[image][image]